# Sorting a set using collections sort

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to sort and need to retain as a set.

So, I am trying convert my `Set` to `List` and use `Collections.sort` and again covert back to a set but facing this error:

> The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)

I tried to sort using `TreeSet` but it sorts lexically so trying to use `Collections.sort`.

```
Set<Object> set = [11, 13, 24, 14, 25, 15, 26, 16, 27, 28, 18, 19, 1, 2, 3, 6];

ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(set);
Collections.sort(list);
```

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Use [`addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: Do you want to sort ints or Strings?

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `TreeSet` is going to be your best option, as per the [constructor documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E()) the default ordering is the natural ordering of the elements. With your specific pseudo-code example (using `Integer`s) this will work pretty much perfectly:

```
var set1 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(
  11, 13, 24, 14, 25, 15, 26, 16, 
  27, 28, 18, 19, 1, 2, 3, 6
)); 
System.out.println(set1);
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
```

If, however, you are using `String`s, then lexical ordering is used, as that's the natural ordering for that type:

```
var set2 = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(
  "11", "13", "24", "14", "25", "15", "26", "16",
  "27", "28", "18", "19", "1", "2", "3", "6" 
)); 
System.out.println(set2);
```

```
[1, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 2, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 3, 6]
```

You have the option of providing a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) to [one of the constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)) to allow you to customise the ordering to your liking:

```
var set3 = new TreeSet<>((String a, String b) -> {
  return Integer.valueOf(a).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b));
}); 
set3.addAll(Arrays.asList(
  "11", "13", "24", "14", "25", "15", "26", "16",
  "27", "28", "18", "19", "1", "2", "3", "6" 
)); 
System.out.println(set3);
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
```